# Forwarding requests using RESTEasy

Tags: java, servlets, proxy, jersey, resteasy

I need to expose couple of resources from microservice A (not Java project) via microservice B (this is Java). Is there any convenient way in Jersey to proxy microservice A so microservice B forwards requests to A and returns those results back?

I can imagine there would be a sub-path like "/api/microservice-b/alias-to-microservice-a/resource-1" and all requests which are going there should be forwarded to microservice A by microservice B but eg. "/api/microservice-b/other-resource-1" and "/api/microservice-b/other-resource-2" should stay the same and processed by microservice B.

Comment: I found a ProxyServlet in Jetty, would that work?

Comment: Are you working with RESTEasy or Jersey?

Comment: I use RESTEasy.

Comment: The biggest challenge I would see is being able to match the URL. You might able to simply do a client call if the path is `/api/microrservice-b/alisas`. You'd need to know the number of parameters passed though.